# Jquery Easing Slider not working in IE9

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-9, jquery-ui-slider

This is a weird one and I need help wrapping my head around a possible solution.

Please visit [nsdstudio.com](http://nsdstudio.com) in IE 9 and see that the slider doesn't load in any images. It should show just a preloader. Any other browser shows the images.

Now go to [woothemes.com](http://woothemes.com) in the same tab and let the site load up. Now go back to [nsdstudio.com](http://nsdstudio.com) and the see that the loader is working!

Anyone have any ideas to how or why this is happening?

Comment: I'm on linux with no IE, but it does sound like you have some kind of nesting event happening in which the first event needed to be fired at least once. So when going away then back seems to work. Also i believe debugbar was an alternative to firefox for IE. Might help.

Answer (score 0):

Set `isPreloaded:false` in *template/lib/lofslider/lofslider.js* (about line 97)

Answer (score 0):

Use these files in same sequence, I tested with IE 9, Slider is working fine

```
jquery.ui.all.css
jquery-1.7.1.min.js
slider.css
jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js
slide.js
```